# Easy way to preview HTML emails

Tags: email, html-email

I'm writing a Rails 4 app and I'm going through the universally tedious process of building an HTML email layout. As we all know, there are a million quirks and gotchas that make it a pain in the ass, often requiring a lot of trial and error. *On top of that*, it's awkward to actually preview the emails without sending them to yourself over and over again (unlike a web page where you can just refresh the browser). **There has to be a better way to develop HTML emails.** What is it?

Answer (score 2):

Try an email rendering preview tool like

- [Litmus](https://litmus.com/email-testing)
- [EmailOnAcid](http://www.emailonacid.com/email-preview)
- [Return Path Inbox Preview](http://www.returnpath.com/solution-content/inbox-preview/)
- [PreviewMyEmail](http://previewmyemail.com/features/email_design_testing/)
- [IBM Email Optimization](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/email-optimization/)
- ...